# Necessity of calling mysqli_result::free_result?

Tags: php

Is it necessary to `free_result()` a `mysqli_result` after being done working with it ?

Could not doing this mean a PHP application can have a memory leak ? Could this basically make a PHP application inefficient or poorly optimised ?

I understand PHP variables are cleared as soon as the script execution is finished therefore I don't see a valid reason to `free_result()` unless I worked with a query returning a huge resultset which is not the case so far.

Comment: ofcourse it's not mandatory but its a good practice to do so.. coz clearing the result will reduce the burden on the browser and the DB..

Comment: If the script is going to exit shortly after you finish using the query results, there's little benefit from it. Most programmers don't bother.